# Laravel - HTTP Session Flash Data dont work

Tags: php, laravel, flash-message

The Laravel documentation:

Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session for the next request. You may do so using the flash method.

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
```

my code:

```
 public function store(StorePost $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate();

        $post = new Posts();
        $post->title = $validated['title'];
        $post->content = $validated['content'];

        $post->save();

        $request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', [$post->id]);
    }
```

and my IDE vscode throw error looks like this:
[error in flash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d7u5.png)

**Some help in this error ?**

Comment: Don't forget add use Session; to your controller. or use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

Comment: I add it' and still not working

Comment: don't think it uses Session class

Comment: You can use the session helper: 
```session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!')``` or you could
```return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post)->with('status', 'Task was successful!');```

Comment: It work with 
redirect()->route('posts.show', $post)->with('status', 'Task was successful!'); 
But why dont work with - flash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you include the following namespace

```
use Session;
```

if not use 'Session' namespace

you can also try another way

```
public function store(StorePost $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate();

        $post = new Posts();
        $post->title = $validated['title'];
        $post->content = $validated['content'];

        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', [$post->id])->with('status','Task was successful!');
    }
```

it will create a RedirectResponse instance and flash data to the session in a single, fluent method

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works so that there will be no doubts. Thank you for the answer. But again the question is why not work with the - flash ?

Comment: This may be because you did not include the 'Session' namespace in your controller

Comment: Yes it's probably because of that

Answer (score 0):

A few things to fix your issue and clean things up a tad. The Laravel convention for naming models is to use the singular name of the table. If you have a table named posts, the model's name should be Post. Second, you don't need a temporary variable for the the validated data, just inline it. Finally, you can use `with` on your redirect to flash your session data:

```
    public function store(StorePost $request)
    {
        $post = Posts::create([
            'title'   => $request->validated('title'),
            'content' => $request->validated('content')
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post)
            ->with('status', 'Task was successful!');
    }
```

Comment: Ok I understand you, but why does not it allows me to use the flash, quite strange because it is in their documentation

Comment: It works so that there will be no doubts. Thank you for the answer. 
But again the question is why not work with the - flash ?

Comment: Have you imported StorePost correctly at the top of your controller? use App\Requests\StorePost; (assuming App\Requests is where you have it)